# spring framework - pass rental_id to make a expenses object out of it

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a spring project, where i want to create a object called 'Expenses' out of our rental_id. But whenever im trying and pressing create, i'll get a white label error.

This is the error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Optional int parameter 'rental_id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type.
```

Here is the code from the homecontroller and repo:

```
@GetMapping("/createExpenses/{rental_id}")
public String createExpenses(@PathVariable("rental_id") int rental_id, Model model){
    return "home/createExpenses";
}

@PostMapping("/createExpenses")
public String createExpenses(@ModelAttribute Expenses expenses, int rental_id){
    expensesService.createExpenses(expenses, rental_id);
    return "home/succesExpense";
}

    public Expenses createExpenses(Expenses e, int rental_id){
            String sql = "INSERT INTO expenses (base_cost, rental_end_date, end_time, drop_off, drop_off_extra, km_end, repair_fee, fuel_level, full_price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) where rental_id = ?;";
            template.update(sql, e.getBase_cost(), e.getRental_end_date(), e.getEnd_time(), e.getDrop_off(), e.getDrop_off_extra(), e.getKm_end(), e.getRepair_fee(), e.getFuel_level(), e.getFull_price(), rental_id);
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a clue in error message. If you use primitive *int*, it cannot have null value. If not initialized, it will have a 0. If you would like it to be an option, you could use a wrapper class for this variable (*Integer*).

I suppose you're trying to create a user using post mapping method. You get your `Expenses` using `@ModelAttribute` which is correct but at the same time you do not extract `rental_id`. So what you get is `Expense` argument and null `rental_id`. Since you cannot assign null to `rental_id` an error is thrown.

**What you can do?**

1. You could create a POJO class that would have both `Expense` and `rental_id` fields. Then use it as you're currently treating you `Expense` argument.
2. Pass `rental_id` as `@PathVariable` as you're doing in first method.